# Apply :style on v-for loop only once - vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to build a heatmap table with Vue.js.

I've been following [this](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-flexible-data-heat-map/) great tutorial made for jquery.

I want to avoid jquery, and everything works fine, however I'm having troubles in the last step `$(this).css({backgroundColor:clr});`

How can I change `:style` only once for each cell? Now it obviously changes the value of each cell once it's at the last loop of the `v-for` loop.

I thought about creating a `watcher` which sees every-time the colour data property is changed and runs a separate function like `changeColour: function(color) {// change css}` but I don't know to which cell apply it.

So far I have:

a basic html table:

```
<tbody v-for="page in json">
  <tr>
    <td style = 'background-color: #e5e5ff'> 
    {{page.page_path}} </td>
    <td :style="{ 'background-color': sessionColor }">
    {{page.sessions}} </td>
    <td :style="{ 'background-color': exitColor }">
    {{page.exit_rate}} </td>
    <td :style="{ 'background-color': bounceClr }">
    {{page.bounce_rate}} </td>
    <td :style="{ 'background-color': timeClr }">
    {{page.avg_time_on_page}} </td>
  </tr>
```

a Vue instance with the 4 colour properties, and a methods which takes care of generating the RGB values.

Here I have the complete jsfiddle, the only thing missing is **v-binding** **style** **once** for each cell. How I can do that? Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/6sLx3su2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this.

replace

```
    this.sessionColor = sessClr;
    this.exitColor = exitClr;
    this.bounceColor = bounceClr;
    this.timeColor = timeClr;,
```

with

```
    this.json[i].sessionColor = sessClr;
    this.json[i].exitColor = exitClr;
    this.json[i].bounceColor = bounceClr;
    this.json[i].timeColor = timeClr;
```

and refer in the html for each entry in json like below:

```
<td :style="{ 'background-color': page.sessionColor }">
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mau5kvjr/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Pradeepb, thank you for the answer. I really like how concise your solution is. One question, are you sure that doing this I'll keep the order on the 4 different `x Axis`? The second Axis (exit rate) seems to load the opposite, i.e. The higher the number the whiter the background

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. It just renders the values you assign. and also please try it then only we will know whether it works or not :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused because of the inverted scale. This is great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help !